# Implementing Observer design

Tags: c++, oop, observer-pattern

I was trying Observer Pattern with some basic implementation using C++. But I got these errors:

Error   C2065   'mod': undeclared identifier    obs_example C:\Users\silae\source\repos\obs_example\Obs.h   9
Error   C2065   'model': undeclared identifier  obs_example C:\Users\silae\source\repos\obs_example\Obs.h   9
Error   C2065   'model': undeclared identifier  obs_example C:\Users\silae\source\repos\obs_example\Obs.h   11
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    obs_example C:\Users\silae\source\repos\obs_example\Obs.h   6
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Subject'  obs_example C:\Users\silae\source\repos\obs_example\Obs.h   8
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    obs_example C:\Users\silae\source\repos\obs_example\Obs.h   6
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   obs_example C:\Users\silae\source\repos\obs_example\Obs.h   6

These are my files:

**Obs.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Subject.h"
class Observer
{
    Subject* model;
public:
    Observer(Subject* mod) {
        model = mod;
        model->attach(this);
    }
virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

**Subject.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Obs.h"
class Subject
{
    std::vector < class Observer* > views; // 3. Coupled only to "interface"
public:
    void attach(Observer *obs) {
        views.push_back(obs);
    }
void notify();
};

void Subject::notify() {
for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    views[i]->update();
}
```

**Class.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Obs.h"
class Class : public Observer
{
    int n1, n2;
public:
    Class(Subject* sub);
    void setNumbers(int, int);
    int sum();
    void update();
};
```

**Class.cpp**

```
#include "Class.h"
#include <iostream>
Class::Class(Subject* sub) :Observer(sub) {}

void Class::setNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    n1 = a;
    n2 = b;
}

int Class::sum()
{
    return n1+n2;
}

void Class::update()
{
    std::cout << "Class update" << std::endl;
}
```

**Class1.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Obs.h"
#include "Class.h"
class Class1: public Observer
{
    int result;
    Class c1, c2;
public:
    Class1(Subject* sub);
    void setNumbers(Class, Class);
    int multiply();
    void update();
};
```

**Class1.cpp**

```
#include "Class1.h"
#include <iostream>

Class1::Class1(Subject* sub): Observer(sub) , c1(sub) , c2(sub){}

void Class1::setNumbers(Class a, Class b)
{
    c1 = a;
    c2 = b;
}

int Class1::multiply()
{
    return c1.sum()* c2.sum();
}

void Class1::update()
{
    std::cout << "Class1 update" << std::endl;
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h"
#include"Class1.h"
#include"Subject.h"
int main()
{
    Subject sub;
    Class c1(&sub), c2(&sub);
    c1.setNumbers(1, 3);
    c2.setNumbers(4, 6);
    std::cout << "1 + 3 = " << c1.sum() << std::endl
        << "4 + 6 = " << " " << c2.sum();
    
    Class1 cl1(&sub);
    cl1.setNumbers(c1,c2);
    std::cout << "(1 + 3) x (4 + 6) =  " << c1.sum() << std::endl;
    sub.notify();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a cyclic dependency in there (`Subject` uses `Observer` and vice versa). For this to work, you have to predeclare one of them before the other. For example remove the include from Obs.h and add the line `class Subject;` before the `Observer` class.

Comment: @n314159 I change Subject.h like this:
`#pragma once
#include <vector>
class Observer;
class Subject
{
    std::vector < Observer* > views;
public:
    void attach(Observer* obs) {
        views.push_back(obs);
    }
    void notify();
};
void Subject::notify() {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
        views[i]->update();
} `
but I got this error for 3 times :
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2027 use of undefined type 'Observer' obs_example C:\Users\silae\source\repos\obs_example\Subject.h ;
Sorry about code block :(

Comment: This new error comes from the fact that `Observer` is only declared and not defined, when you use it (`views[i]->update()`). This can be resolved by moving the definitions of the functions into a `*.cpp` file that includes both `Obs.h` and `Subject.h`. Please Edit your answer when you change the code since that is much more readable.